# How to cancel interpreter command in emacs python-mode

Tags: python, emacs

If I mistype a command in the python intepreter, sometimes I just see `...`. For example if I type `help(random.unif` and press enter I cannot enter a new command.  I have to exit emacs and start python and the interpreter again. Is there  way to correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Pavel Anossov explains, you want to send Python a CTRL-C to interrupt it.

But in emacs, by default, <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> is a prefix key.

Fortunately, in most interactive-shell modes, including python-mode and the alternatives, hitting <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> twice in a row sends a ctrl-C to the interpreter. Or, more technically, <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd><kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> is bound to `comint-interrupt-subjob`. (You can, of course, run it any other way—even <kbd>META-X comint-interrupt-subjob</kbd> if you really want.) The result looks like this:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(f
...   ^C ^C
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Another alternative is to use the `quoted-insert` command, usually bound to <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>. However, because this will not interrupt the usual line input, you will usually have to follow it with a newline. The result looks like this:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(f
... ^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> works. Not sure about emacs-embedded interpreter. Alternatively, just provide the interpreter with whatever it's waiting for (in your example, an `)`).

Comment: The problem is knowing _how_ to send <kbd>CTRL-C</kdb> to the emacs interpeter (and also how to get it to interrupt the normal `readline`-esque mode the same way <kdb>CTRL-C</kdb> does in the console, although if you fail to do that and just send a line with nothing but <kbd>CTRL-C</kdb> in it, that basically works too).